# Unity2d Infinite Scrolling : Why Scrolling Background does not appear when Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, infinite-scroll, unity-webgl

I'm trying to do a game that moves the character from left to right with an infinite vertical background. Im trying to build with webgl. But the scrolling area doesn't appear on screen when i build and run. In unity Game view it looks fine, everything works as it should but when in desktop chrome browser, everything works fine except that the scrolling area is not visible.

[image from unity game view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdFAI.jpg)

[image in desktop chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec8Yr.jpg)

My code is just 2 lines in an Update

```
 using UnityEngine;

 public class InfiniteScrolling: MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float scrollSpeed = 1f;
     public float clampPos;

     [HideInInspector] public Vector3 StartPosition;

     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         StartPosition = transform.position;
     }

     void Update()
     {
         float NewPosition = Mathf.Repeat(Time.time * scrollSpeed, clampPos);
         transform.position = StartPosition + Vector3.down * NewPosition;
     }
 }
```

**UPDATE: SOLVED**
Somehow on start the values of the x position of the game objects changed. like whatever values that was set in inspector didnt translate when in Game on start. so i set the x position of the game objects transform in script in Start()

Comment: Does it work fine when you build it on the desktop?

Comment: Hey @Stephan the "game" (character move left and right) works on desktop but the side "walls" don't appear. like the images i attached

Comment: In the sprite renderer component of your BackgroundSprite, try to increase the number of order in layer to a positive number like maybe +2 or +3. If this doesn't work, increase your z-position to a positive number in the transform component.

Comment: somehow on start the x position of the game objects changed. like whatever values were set in the inspector didnt translate on start. so i ended up setting the x values of the game objects transform.